# Possible set of fibers of a point-wise limit of a sequence of continuous real functions.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A fiber of a function $f$ is any non-empty $f^{-1}\{y\}=\{x: f(x)=y\}.$

It is elementary that, with the standard topology on $\Bbb R,$ if $f$ is the point-wise limit of a sequence of continuous $f_n:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R,$ then every fiber of $f$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

Let $P$ be the set of every $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ that is a point-wise limit of a sequence of continuous real functions.

Q. If $F$ is a pair-wise disjoint family of non-empty $G_{\delta}$ subsets of $\Bbb R,$  with $\cup F=\Bbb R,$ does there exist $f\in P$ such that the set of fibers of $f$ is $F$?

Note: I just thought of this Q a few minutes ago. It's not homework; I'm 68.

Comment: Is it okay if $\cup F$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R?$

Comment: @Ultradark . I think the A to my Q by Reveillark implies that the A to your Q is "OK. It doesn't matter." Good Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be the collection of all pairwise disjoint families of $G_\delta$ whose union is $\mathbb{R}$. Since there are continuum many Baire-1 functions (what you called $P$), it suffices to show that $|\mathfrak{X}|$ is greater than the continuum. But any partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into finite sets belongs to $\mathfrak{X}$, and there are $2^\mathfrak{c}$ such partitions.

To see the last part, given $A\subset (0,\infty)$, consider the partition
$$
p_A:=\{\{0\}\}\cup \{\{x,-x\}:x\in A\}\cup \{\{x\}:x>0 \wedge x\not\in A\}\cup \{\{x\}:x<0\wedge -x\not\in A\}
$$
For $A\neq B$, $p_A\neq p_B$, as desired.

Comment: I couldn't recall the correct term so I just called it $P$.